# Approximation of a function by a polynomial (Chebyshev First Kind, Bernstein, etc...) containing only even degrees and constants in a given Range[a,b]

Tags: functions, function-construction, polynomials, approximation, coefficients

In Mathematica, how can I create a polynomial function containing only even degrees and constants?

That is, I have a function:

$f(x)=\frac{\pi ^2}{\left(\frac{\pi }{2}-\tan ^{-1}(k (x-1))\right)^2}$

And I'm looking for a function that generates such a polynomial approximation on arbitrary range with Chebyshev First Kind, Bernstein or another in form:

$p(x) = c_0 + c_1 \cdot x^2+ ... + c_m \cdot x^m$

where $m$ - maximum even degree of polynom.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
pars = {k = 1, Subscript[ω, 0] = 1, Δ = 5}
f = (-ArcTan[k (x - Subscript[ω, 0])] + Pi/2)/Pi
Plot[f, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
p[x_] = 1/f^2
Plot[1/f^2, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All]
P = Collect[
   N[InterpolatingPolynomial[{{0, 0}, {Subscript[ω, 0]/2, 
       p[Subscript[ω, 0]/2]}, {Subscript[ω, 0], 
       p[Subscript[ω, 0]]}, {Δ/2, 
       p[Δ/2]}, {Δ, p[Δ]}}, 
     x]], x] // Simplify
Plot[{1/f^2, P}, {x, 0, 2}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Somewhere on the Internet I read information that in order to get rid of odd degrees you need to include the point *{0,0}* in the polynomial, which I did with the usual **InterpolatingPolynomial** command.
Despite this, the odd degrees in the polynomial have been preserved.

**EDIT:**

```
pars = {k = 10, Subscript[ω, 0] = 1, Δ = 5}
model = Pi^2/(ArcTan[k*(t - Subscript[ω, 0])] - Pi/2)^2
f[t_] := Evaluate[model];
data = {#, f[#]} & /@ Table[t, {t, 0, 5, .01}];
lp = ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.01]}, 
  DisplayFunction -> Identity]
F = Fit[data, {1, t^2, t^4, t^8}, t, 
  FitRegularization -> {"Tikhonov", 1}]
p1 = Plot[{model, F}, {t, 0, 3}];
p2 = Plot[{Abs[model - F]}, {t, 0, 3}];
GraphicsRow[{p1, p2}]
```

We can use **Fit**.
But, with large $k = 10$, the first graph shows that up to about $t = 1$ there is a fairly straight section, which then goes into a quadratic graph. In this area, the function is poorly approximated by almost all the tools. This area is important. 
Is there any way to improve the quality of approximation on it?

Comment: Analytically, the even/odd distinction is usually only applied when the number $0$ can be considered the center of the domain (i.e., the whole real line or when $a=-b$). I’ve never run into such an approach over an arbitrary interval.  I’ve seen a modified approach in which the basis functions are centered at $c=(a+b)/2$. For example, $(x-(a+b)/2)^n$.  Note that not every interpolation problem can be solved with just the even power functions. For example, $(-1,-1),\,(0,0),\,(1,1)$ cannot be interpolated using only even degrees.

Comment: @MichaelE2 - Well, and if you remove the arbitrary range and leave those requirements for it that you designated. Which polynomials to choose and how to make the approximating polynomial contain only even degrees if the approximated function behaves in a manner similar to quadratic functions?

Comment: I mean $x^4+x^2+1$ or $x^{16}+x^4+1$ etc...

Comment: If the function is even, interpolate at points symmetrically place about the center $x = 0$.  If the function is not an even function, perhaps what you want is something like `LinearModelFit[data, {x^2, x^4, x^6}, x] // Normal`, where `data = Table[{x, f[x]}, {x, a, b, (b-a)/1000}]`.  Somehow, I got it into my head you wanted an interpolation, but using the `*Fit` family of function seems a better fit, now that I reread the question.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the update. Your basis contains the odd power `t`, instead of consisting of all even powers.  Are you allowing any powers, or just even ones? [You do realize that you cannot approximate your function very well just using even powers, yes?]

Comment: @Michael E2 - Please, see my edit.Yes, without odd degrees, the approximation is much worse. But odd degrees are not acceptable. This is the contradiction. Is there any way around this?

Comment: I pretty sure that the `Fix` method solves a (discretized) least squares problem and gives the optimal solution $p(x) = a_0+a_2x^2+a_4x^4+\cdots+a_nx^n$ with respect to the norm $[\sum (f(x_j)-p(x_j))^2]^{1/2}$.  It is optimal in the sense that there is not another polynomial $q$ of degree at most $n$ for which the error is smaller.  Omitting the odd terms means the error must be at least a certain amount, which could be large.  Since I think it is optimal, I don't think I know how to improve it, except maybe omit `FitRegularization`.

Comment: @Michael E2 - Your advice was helpful. I took advantage of it and got an acceptable result. In addition, I tried fitting polynomial coefficients (see the _Properties and Relations_ section) - [https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinimize.html).

While I do not understand how to add a constraint on the localization of the roots of the fitting polynomial in the left half-plane of the complex plane? How can this be done?